# DataBinding issues after updating to AndroidX?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, androidx

I'm using databinding in my project. But after updating all the dependencies, it shows the below error.

> error: cannot find symbol class AddCrop

I tried cleaning the project, Invalidating cache & Restart, Renaming the layout files.

I'm using this library for Data Binding. I have seen a Similar Issue in this library too > https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter/issues/131

Please help me to solve this issue ?

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.puramtech.myfarmer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro_placeholder'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:localizationactivity:1.2.1'

//    Arch Components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0"
    implementation 'com.github.Ilhasoft:data-binding-validator:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.zhihu.android:matisse:0.4.3'
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra-core:5.1.1'
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra-http:5.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.stephentuso:welcome:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.lawloretienne:imagegallery:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    implementation 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2:bindingcollectionadapter:3.0.0-beta3'
    implementation 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2:bindingcollectionadapter-recyclerview:3.0.0-beta3'

}
```

**ACTIVITY**

```
public class AddCropActivity extends BaseActivity {

    ActivityAddcroppBinding binding;
    AddCropViewModel mViewModel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_addcropp);
        AddCropViewModelFactory factory = InjectorUtils.provideAddCropViewModelFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), mSelected);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(AddCropViewModel.class);
        binding.setViewModel(mViewModel);
        binding.setActivity(this);

        validator = new Validator(binding);

        permissionHelper = new PermissionHelper(this);

        isEDIT = getIntent().getStringExtra("ACTION").equalsIgnoreCase("EDIT");

        initToolbar();


        mViewModel.getCroptype(
                Utils.getLang(getCurrentLanguage().getISO3Language())).observe(AddCropActivity.this, apiResponse -> {
            if (apiResponse != null && isEDIT) {
                if (apiResponse.getError() == null) {
                    List<CropType> crops = (List<CropType>) apiResponse.getList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < apiResponse.getList().size(); i++) {
                        if (crops.get(i).getCropType().equalsIgnoreCase(cropType)) {
                            pos = i;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        binding.executePendingBindings();

        binding.progressBar.hide();

        mViewModel.getImageCount().observe(this, integer -> {
            count = (integer != null ? integer : 0);
            binding.attachImages.setText("ATTACH IMAGES (" + count + ")");

            if(count == 0)
                binding.attachImages.setEnabled(false);
            else
                binding.attachImages.setEnabled(true);

        });
    }


    private void initToolbar() {
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(isEDIT ? "Edit Crops" : "Add Crops");
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

}
```

**LAYOUT**

```
<data>

    <import type="com.puramtech.myfarmer.R" />

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.puramtech.myfarmer.ui.AddCrop.AddCropViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="activity"
        type="com.puramtech.myfarmer.ui.AddCrop.AddCropActivity" />

</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="14dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/crop_type"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:itemBinding="@{viewModel.singleItem}"
                app:itemIds="@{viewModel.itemIds}"
                app:items="@{viewModel.croptype}" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/image_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:itemBinding="@{viewModel.editImageItem}"
                    app:items="@{viewModel.items}"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/attach_images"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button"
                android:onClick="@{()->activity.onImageAttach()}"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="@string/attach_crop_images"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check your gradle.properties and confirl this 2 line is there or not?
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true

Comment: Yes. I have enabled it already...

Comment: Does this issue result in build failures or only in issues with the IDE?

Comment: Build Failure. I cannot run the App in the device :(

Comment: Note for others: There's also a (currently unanswered) issue on the repo: https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter/issues/152

Comment: I may have misunderstood the issue here, but your code in the layout references a method "onImageAttach()" that is missing in the AddCropActivity.class. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Could you add the code from `AddCropActivityBinding` file?

Comment: @N1234 Since the activity file has a lot of code. I removed some code but the "onImageAttach()" is in the Activity code.